# Count number of objects in a list using Java8 Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So I am trying to count the number of objects in an ArrayList using just Stream.
I am using **stream.count** but that is only **returning 1** where as my list has more than 1 objects. Here is some code:

```
 static ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

  void loadCourses(){ // putting Person objects in the list }

  public void countPeople()
{
    Stream<ArrayList<Person>> stream1 = Stream.of(people); 
    long l = stream1.count();
    System.out.println("Number of people loaded: " + l);

}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a `Stream<ArrayList<Person>>` rather than a `Stream<Person>`.

You want:

```
long l = people.stream().count();
```

You are getting `1` because there is only one `ArrayList`.

Note also that you do not need streams for this. You can just do `people.size()`.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to @PaulBoddington answer: I strongly encourage you to use simply `people.size()`. In Java-8 when you do this using a stream like `people.stream().count()`, it actually iterates over the whole `Collection`. So this code effectively works like this:

```
long count = 0;
for(Person p : people) count++;
return count;
```

This could be enormously slow for big collections. In contrast `people.size()` just returns the value of the size field stored inside the `ArrayList`.

This problem is already fixed in Java-9 code (see [JDK-8067969](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067969)), but this fix is not backported to Java-8.